# Is it possible to create a drop down list in excel that show data from a specific field from an access table?

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu

Helo I'm trying to create a calculation sheet in excel that I wanted to have a drop down cell where user could select one product name from a existing access database. I also wanted to retrieve in another excel cell the price of selected product that is also in the access database (like a procv command, but retrieving data from access). Does anybody know how to do it? I wanted to avoid to replicate source access table in excel. I wanted something more direct. I konw some basic VBA if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, directly linking a control in Excel to an Access database isn't going to be possible.  These products just weren't intended to work this way.  Typically one would create a form in Access and on that form have the combo box reference the table there.  Other user input could be added and calculations done etc, and then the final calculated values could be exported to Excel for further manipulation if needed/desired (that can easily be done in VBA).

That said, an indirect link could be done using VBA.  You would add the "Microsoft Access 16.0 Object Library" reference library, create a connection, db and recordset objects. There are tons of resources via Google (or here) on how to do this.

With those in place you can conduct SQL queries against the database to pull the data over and update the combobox by clearing it's contents then re-adding from the query.  You can put the code to update the combobox in any trigger you need.

Otherwise, the only other way would be to do what you said you didn't want to, replicate the database table in Excel.

I hope this points you in the right direction!  Good luck!